# Как настроить wp-json в nginx?

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь настроить wp-json, но nginx ругается. Выдаёт  ошибку 404
Подскажите что не так в моём конфиге

```
        location /wordpress/ {

            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/blog/index.php?$args;

            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^/wordpress/wp-json/ {
            rewrite ^/wordpress/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
        }
```

Comment: А зачем второй `location` вообще? Думаю, без него всё будет работать прекрасно.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл откуда взялся второй location) Но думаю тем не менее это не всегда необходимо. В любом случае заработает если вы измените `rewrite`, учитывая что блог в сабдиректории:

```
        location /wordpress/ {

            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/blog/index.php?$args;

            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^/wordpress/wp-json/ {
            rewrite ^/wordpress/wp-json/(.*?)$ /wordpress/?rest_route=/$1 last;
        }
```